# Titanium Backup Dropbox sync scheduling

Tags: dropbox, titanium-backup

I'm using Titanium Backup to automatically back up to my SD card. I also managed to get the "Sync to Dropbox " feature to work. How I can I automate "Sync To Dropbox"? I don't see it as an option when I add a schedule.

Comment: Is it not immediately synced when something changes?

Comment: Matthew, the timestamps on the files in dropbox are set to when I manually ran it. It doesn't appear to be doing it automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was added in a recent update as a pro-only feature.

```
Edit schedule -> when finished -> Sync to Dropbox
```

Comment: Note that this is only available in the Titanium Backup Pro version.

Comment: Didn't realize this, edited to reflect this.

Comment: Could not find it.. So, click on `Edit` and in the pop-up window scroooooll down to the bottom. See? :)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Titanium Backup didnt work like what i wanted it to do. So now i use RealSync Pro, witch automatically syncs all photos from phone to dropbox each time i'm on my home wifi network.

Works great!

Get it [HERE](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.designoid.therealsync.pro&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5kZXNpZ25vaWQudGhlcmVhbHN5bmMucHJvIl0.).

Answer (score 0):

Titanium Backup doesn't have this feature yet. But, you can do this to automate it:

1. Install [Dropsync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync).
2. Link TitaniumBackup directory (whatever it is) with a folder on Dropbox.
3. Configure Auto Sync interval of Dropsync to whatever you want (Scheduling).

Done!

Free version of Dropsync allows only one directory sync which is enough for this job. I have been using Dropsync for 5 months and I haven't faced any issues yet.

Comment: It's a pro-only feature that was added a while ago.

Comment: Yup.. I've re-checked it after your answer. It was there! Thanks..